# create calendar table and join it to my table - lost as can be

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I am not great at MYSQL but am trying to learn. I need to create a calendar table and LEFT JOIN it to my datatable. The reason is I am counting bookings each week and need t to show "0" if there are no bookings for that week. I cant use a standard calendar table I dont think because I dont want to have to manually fill in each week for all of eternity. I am looking for a solution that can add dates into the future once set up without human oversight. This should be dynamic and never ending unlike some examples I have found.I am on MYSQL 5.4

For the calendar table I have cobbled together this but don't think it is right:

```
SELECT 
DATE(booking_date + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(booking_date)) DAY) EndOfWeekDate
FROM my_table
group by EndOfWeekDate
ORDER BY EndOfWeekDate DESC
```

and am trying to LEFT JOIN the above to:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(booking_date, "%M %d %Y") AS week_Ending, CONCAT(YEAR(booking_date), '/', WEEK(booking_date)) AS week_name,
DATE(booking_date + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(booking_date)) DAY) EndOfWeekDate,
YEAR(booking_date), WEEK(booking_date), COUNT(*)
FROM my_table
GROUP BY EndOfWeekDate
ORDER BY EndOfWeekDate DESC
```

I am nowhere close to being able to get this right after toying for about 2 hours.  Would someone a lot more experienced than me be able to illuminate where I should be going in order to make this happen?

**Desired Display:**

June 30 2020   |    2020/26   | 2020       |    26     |    5
July 6th 2020      |    2020/27   | 2020       |    27     |    0
July 13 2020       |    2020/28   | 2020       |    28     |    0
July 20 2020       |    2020/29   | 2020       |    29     |    2

**Sample data**
ID | Date | NAME
12 | 2020-08-24 | Bob Smith

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. It looks like you are only selecting from one table (`my_table`) so it's not really that clear as to what you are trying to accomplish. In order to use a `LEFT JOIN` you have to have 2 tables you are selecting from. Please provide an example of the data that is in your table as well as an example of what you want the result set to look like.

Comment: Thanks editing now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Ted Basically what you have to do is create a derived table that you can `LEFT JOIN` your existing table to so every day in the month will be listed and you can display data from your table for the days where it is present. This query is copy/paste ready, all you need to do is change the references to `my_table` to be the table name you want to get the data from.

Here's the example query:

```
SELECT `dateList`.`Date` AS `Date`,
    CONCAT(YEAR(`dateList`.`Date`),'/',DAY(`dateList`.`Date`)) AS `year_month`,
    YEAR(`dateList`.`Date`) AS `year`,
    DAY(`dateList`.`Date`) AS `day`,
    'Bob Smith' AS `name`, 
    CASE WHEN `mt`.`date` IS NULL THEN 0
    ELSE COUNT(`mt`.`id`) 
    END AS `amt`
FROM

-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- this is the part you can copy/paste to be used to left join in a table of your choice ----------------------------------
(
    SELECT `a`.`Date`
    FROM (
        SELECT LAST_DAY('2020-08-01') - INTERVAL (`a`.`a` + (10 * `b`.`a`) + (100 * `c`.`a`)) DAY AS `Date`
        FROM (SELECT 0 AS `a` UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS `a`
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS `a` UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS `b`
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT 0 AS `a` UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) AS `c`
    ) AS `a` 
    WHERE `a`.`Date` BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND LAST_DAY('2020-08-01')
) AS `dateList` 
-- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

LEFT JOIN `my_table` AS `mt` ON `dateList`.`Date` = DATE(`mt`.`date`)
    AND `mt`.`name` = 'Bob Smith'
GROUP BY `dateList`.`Date`
ORDER BY `dateList`.`Date` ASC
```

[Here is a working example in sql fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e16ed5/4)

Let me know if this doesn't make sense or if you need something different.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write this all up. This looks like it has a huge undertaking and I couldn't more appreciate the time you took to do this. I have looked at the fiddle and implemented this in MyPHPAdmin to get the same data. The question I have is - How do I make this go further back and further forward than the month of August?

Comment: @Ted all you would need to do is to change the beginning date in the `BETWEEN` statement on this line: `WHERE a.Date BETWEEN '2020-08-01' AND LAST_DAY('2020-08-01')` to the first day of the month you want to go to. for example, say you wanted to query from July 2020 through August 2020, the line would be this: `WHERE a.Date BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND LAST_DAY('2020-08-01')`

Comment: Got it. I was trying to change the last day thinking that was the "first." This will continue to populate into the future as long as there are bookings? I tried altering a booking to be 9/23 and re-ran the query but the table still shows only as far as 9/6.

Comment: @Ted it should show future dates if you changed the value in both of the spots for `LAST_DAY` to `LAST_DAY('2020-09-01')`. if you wanted it to be dynamic based off of the current date you could change the spots for `LAST_DAY` to be `LAST_DAY(NOW())`.  If it still keeps giving you only through 09/06/2020 and it should be going through 09/23/2020 because you changed the data, try to re-create it in sql fiddle so i can actually see it happening and I can help you troubleshoot it further

Comment: Thanks so much. I will use the NOW() for now and see what happens in a couple of weeks to make sure it ads as we go. Again, thanks for the extra time and thought you put into teaching me on this. Through your example I have learned a lot and how to do this in the future too